# How to fix and compile this C++ program

Tags: c++

In nestClassDef.h I have written code like this

```
  class A{
    public:
     class B{
         public:
           void BTest();
     };
 };

   class B{

   };
```

then in the nestClassDef.cpp I am writing code like this

```
      #include "nestClassDef.h"
      #include<iostream>

      void A::B::BTest(){
        cout<<"Hello World!";
     }

    int main(){
      A a;
      A.B b;
      b.BTest();
    }
```

But when I am compiling the above code

```
       g++ -o nestClassDef nestClassDef.cpp
```

I am getting error like this :-

```
      nestClassDef.cpp: In member function ‘void A::B::BTest()’:
      nestClassDef.cpp:5: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
      nestClassDef.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
      nestClassDef.cpp:10: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token
      nestClassDef.cpp:11: error: ‘b’ was not declared in this scope
```

I am at a loss how to fix this. Any understanding shared will be thankfully received.

Comment: At first I would consider indenting the code sensible. It's ignored by  the compiler but helps human readers. Second you should specify the namespace, it's `std::cout`.

Comment: In case people suggest to write `using namespace std;`, read this first. It is usually [a terrible idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Did you consider asking google about "error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope"? It gives hundreds of copies of the answer...

Comment: I admit it's a mistake not to have referred google at first but I was compounded by two error messages so was little confused.

Comment: Thanks @juanchopanza lesson learnt will use the std::cout all the time.

Comment: When there are several errors, start with the first one. The others might just mean that the first error confused the compiler enough to start saying nonsense.

Comment: Oh! ok got it, will follow this now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the cout error: it's in `std` namespace, so use `std::cout`.

For The second error: `B` is not `A's` member, it's a nested type, so you have to use `A::B b;`

Answer (score 2):

```
  nestClassDef.cpp: In member function ‘void A::B::BTest()’:
  nestClassDef.cpp:5: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
```

Use `std::cout` instead of `cout`, or add `using namespace std;` (probably after your `#include` statements).

```
  nestClassDef.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
  nestClassDef.cpp:10: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token
  nestClassDef.cpp:11: error: ‘b’ was not declared in this scope
```

Use `A::B` instead of `A.B`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `using namespace std;` or use `std::cout` instead of just `cout`
2. Use `A::B` not `A.B`. Dot operator is used on objects or structs/unions.